# failed to run the cfgtest package for domino Note

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, domino-appdev-pack

I follow the instruction to install the node application for IAM Service. I don't know what is going wrong, so that the node application is running with errors.
https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/setup-guide-cfgtest1.html

```
[![dump screen of npm install c:\temp\domino-domino-db-1.11.1.tgz c:\temp\domino-node-iam-client-2.2.0.tgz][1]][1]
```

[image]

```
[![dump screen of npm install][2]][2]
```

[image]
Extract the detail log:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.10.0
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 4ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms

558 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://artifactory.cwp.pnp-hcl.com/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/semver/-/semver-7.3.5.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
558 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
558 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
558 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
558 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)
558 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
558 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
558 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
559 verbose cwd C:\cfgtest\package
560 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
561 verbose node v16.15.0
562 verbose npm  v8.10.0
563 error code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
564 error errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
565 error network request to https://artifactory.cwp.pnp-hcl.com/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/semver/-/semver-7.3.5.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
566 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
566 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
566 error network
566 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
566 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
567 verbose exit 1
568 timing npm Completed in 263995ms
569 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1655378070839
...
911 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@babel/code-frame 1655378074527
912 verbose code 1
913 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
913 error     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-16T11_14_30_296Z-debug-0.log


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUMnI.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEBq7.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Please delete the npm-shrinkwrap.json file.  That was not meant to ship.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is a good chance you need to delete the `"@domino/domino-db"` and `"@domino/node-iam-client"` from package.json before trying to install them from the `.tgz` file. Atleast I had to do that.